# In Star Fluxx, how does the game end with Play all?

Tags: fluxx

I know that there has been complaints about [other cards being overpowered](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/14015/in-star-fluxx-have-you-needed-to-change-how-the-computer-and-the-unseen-force-p), but after playing a few games with my sister, who had never played before, she won almost every game by strategically using the play all card.

Her strategy was to remove the hand limit, increase the draw limit and decrease the play limit so that she could keep her cards in her hand. She would then wait until she got the play all card and a goal that matched two of the keepers in her hand. Then she would win the game by playing the play all rule and then playing only the cards she needed to win.

I thought that perhaps the rules required for all cards to be played first and then determine if she had won, but she reminded me that I had told her "The game ends when the current goal conditions are met".

So what's the actual verdict on this situation?

Comment: This strategy doesn't rely on the "play all" card at all... she could do it with "play 3" also, or by playing the keepers and the goal one at a time with "play 1". Plus, this strategy requires her to have the ability to increase the draw, decrease the play, and have no one else change the rules she plays... Any player who happens to end up with "play all" in their hand, along with 2 keepers that match a goal they have would win as well... that's not a particular strategy, that's just playing the cards you draw correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your sister is correct. The [Fluxx rules](http://www.looneylabs.com/sites/default/files/literature/Fluxx5.0_Rules.pdf) do say that "as soon as someone meets these conditions, they win!"

I don't think this should be an issue, it requires her to find the "play all" (or play 3, etc.) card and there are plenty of ways you can disrupt her strategy:

- Change the rules so that there is a hand limit
- Change the rules to increase the play limit
- Use an action or surprise card to disrupt this strategy: Trash a new rule, Trade hands, rotate hands, rules reset, That's Mine! etc.

Comment: I figured as much, however I did try these strategies but she still thrashed me. I'd play a hand limit, she'd trash the rule, I'd discard the play all card, she'd use the time portal to get it back, I traded hands, she reassigned creepers. Here I was thinking it was a game of luck.

Comment: Flux IS a game of luck... there's some basic tactics that you can do to increase your chances of winning, and you need to be smart enough to play the right cards in the right order to win when you can, but ultimately it's 95% luck.

Comment: If she was able to trash your hand limit rule, and get the Time Portal to get Play All, and reassign creepers, etc... those are all things that she was very lucky to be able to do. And once again, "play all" has very little to do with what you are describing.

Answer (score 1):

She is right, the game ends instantly when someone meets the current goal requirement, even if that person isn't the current player.

> The game continues until someone meets the conditions of the current Goal. That player wins instantly, no matter whose turn it is!

Listed under "winning" in [the rules for normal Fluxx](http://www.looneylabs.com/lit/rules/fluxx-rules), and I'm pretty sure Star Fluxx is no different.